Received the email in only one Shared Mailbox even if the receiver / To is 3 Shared Mailbox emails
I'm working with a C# console app. There are 3 shared mailbox. I need to make sure that when a user sends an email in one of the shared mailbox, the email will go to the corresponding shared mailbox even if the user puts the 3 shared mailbox address in To.
Is there a way to filter that?
Thanks
Have'nt tried anything, new to console app. Outlook 2016 version
